# Return the smallest positive integer that does not occur in an array A of N integers using Function- int solution(vector<int> &A);

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

Write a function:

```
int solution(vector<int> &A);
```

that, given an array `A` of `N` integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in `A`.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [-1, -3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

`N` is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array `A` is an integer within the range [-1,000,000..1,000,000].

**My solution below had 100% correctness but performance was only 25%.
What can I do to improve my performance rating?**

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    int s=A.size();
    int x = 1;
    bool neg=true;
    for (int i=0; i<s;i++){     //check if all integers are negative
        if (A[i]>0){            
            neg = false;        
            goto check;
        }
    }
    check:
    if (neg==true){
        return x;     //returns 1 if all integers are negative
    }
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<s; j++){         
            if (A[j] == x ){
                x=A[j]+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

[this is my codility score.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4I9.png)

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. Doing that will only cause you to get down votes and close votes.

Comment: For a review you can ask your question at this [review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: To ask about improvements for already working code ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com please.

Comment: You don't need to improve the code, you need to improve the algorithm. The code you have uses nested for loops `for (int i=0; i<s; i++){` This means the time taken is proportional to `s squared` which is very ineffecient. Seems to me that if your sorted the vector first, then you could just make a single scan through the vector looking for the first missing integer. So your nested loops have been replaced by a single loop. Much more efficient.

Comment: This problem has `O(N)` solution. Consider mapping `i -> A[i] -> A[A[i]] -> ...` and think about cycles it generates or fails to generate.

Comment: Your code has runtime `O(N^2)`. You can do this in `O(N)` though by using a unordered set or a `std::vector<bool>` where you mark the positive numbers present and then iterate though the possible values checking via that collection...

Comment: @john Yeah, that was it. Sorted before loop and got a 100% performance rating!

Comment: Sorting takes `O(n log n)` time. I wonder if you could get an above 100% performance rating.

Comment: Note, code review is for improving working code. Code that does not meet any required objective, including the performance objective, cannot be considered working.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments your approach takes `O(n^2)` time.

To get faster results you need a better algorithm.

One thing mentioned was sorting the vector. Throw away everything <= 0 at the same time and then you can just go through the resulting vector and check for the first hole. That gets you down to `O(n log n)` time.

The other algorithm mentioned was to use an unordered set or `vector<bool>` and mark all the numbers present and then find the first one not present. Note that the answer must be a number between 1 and n + 1 for an input of n numbers. So you can greatly reduce the size of the unordered set or vector you need. At most 12.5kb of memory.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, my solution below scored 100% on codility in all sections. Idea is to maintain a candidate as we punch out possible candidates from a second array. It's in C btw.

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
    int i, j, rv;

    rv = 1;;
    int arr[10000002] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (A[i] < 1)
            continue;
        if (arr[A[i]] == 0)
            arr[A[i]] = 1;
        if (A[i] == rv) {
            for (j = rv + 1; j < 10000002; j++) {
                if (arr[j] == 0) {
                    rv = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int solution(const std::vector<int>& A) {
    std::unordered_set<int> numSet(begin(A), end(A));
    int result = 1;
    while (numSet.count(result) > 0) {
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```